# Terribly slow performance debugging project with VS2019 Enterprise

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I'm having trouble with Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise with one of my projects.
Trying to load any of the pages that access the database results in the page taking 6~ seconds to load, this is pretty annoying when trying to debug/test the application.

I've disabled IntelliTrace already.

Debugging with VSCode is about 10x faster, see the following screenshots of a timer wrapped around a single database method.

Here is VS2019
[image: VS 2019]

Here is VSCode
[image: VS Code]

Comment: Ahm, so `use VSCode` then?

Comment: Check Control Panel and see how much memory you are using.  When you exceed the amount of memory in a machine swap space is used which can slow down an application.

Comment: Really usefull that one thanks @zaitsman.
Memory isn't an issue 64GB in this machine.

Comment: @JordanCoulam this comes with the question. Performance of VS can be impacted by a multitude of factors, from hardware ones to your actual code to profiling tools you use to any extensions you use. VS Code most likely bypasses some of these issues. The way you asked the question it is impossible to answer it.

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the same database?

Comment: This is a fresh install of VS 2019 with 0 extensions. The same code results in 300ms with VSCode. I do want to use Visual Studio because of the paid extensions I have.
The machine is a 6 core I7 with 64GB ram.

Comment: Yeah I'm opening the same project, DB details are in appsettings.json.
Can confirm though